# Glide error when build release apk

Tags: android-glide, android-proguard, dexguard

In my case, I found this error when create release apk.

- App module has lib module.
- Lib module has Glide and use Dexguard -keepresourcexmlelements  - manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule.
- App module use Proguard.

How can i fixed it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You included a DexGuard-only rule (-keepresourcexmlelements) in the proguard rules for your app. You need to cleanup your rule file and ensure that you do not include DexGuard specific rules in your consumer proguard files of the library.